# Expected identifier or '('

Tags: c

Am getting this compiling error, but can't figure out why. Error message is commented.

```
float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB);
{                                           // Expected identifier or '('
    return 180 - (angleA + angleB);
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        float angleA = 30.0;
        float angleB = 60.0;
        float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB);
        printf("The third angle is %.2f", angleC);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a semi-colon at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the semi-colon between the function declaration and the opening brace